# Stack: how to build with lts-13.2? I want to use newer libraries

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am using stack for some of my Haskell projects. Up until now, I was having no trouble; but since lts-13.1 I get a weird built error.

When I setup up a new project with `stack new foo && cd foo`, and then run `stack setup --ghc-build standard`, I get this huge repetitive error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(Interpreter.thr_o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(CheckUnload.thr_o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(CheckUnload.thr_o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_32 reloc against 'linker_unloaded_mutex' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(Scav.thr_o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(Scav.thr_o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(Scav.thr_o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(Scav.thr_o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(Scav.thr_o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(Scav.thr_o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(Compact.thr_o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(Compact.thr_o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(Compact.thr_o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_32 reloc which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(Evac_thr.thr_o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_32 reloc against 'stg_WHITEHOLE_info' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(Evac_thr.thr_o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_32 reloc against 'stg_WHITEHOLE_info' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(MarkWeak.thr_o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(MarkWeak.thr_o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(MarkWeak.thr_o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_32 reloc which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(Evac.thr_o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libHSrts_thr.a(Evac.thr_o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_32 reloc against 'stg_WHITEHOLE_info' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libCffi.a(ffi64.o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libCffi.a(unix64.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'abort' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libCffi.a(ffiw64.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_32 reloc against 'ffi_closure_win64' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
```

...hundreds more of the same...

```
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/rts/libCffi.a(win64.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'abort' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`clang' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

--  While building simple Setup.hs using:
      /home/georg/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.3/bin/ghc -rtsopts -threaded -clear-package-db -global-package-db -hide-all-packages -package base -main-is StackSetupShim.mainOverride -package Cabal-2.4.0.1 /home/georg/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.hs /home/georg/.stack/setup- 
   exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs -o /home/georg/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64- 
   linux/tmp-Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.3
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I think this has something to do with lts-13.1/2 or my Arch Linux/gcc installation, because when I change `resolver: lts-13.2` to `resolver: lts-12.4` in `stack.yaml`, it builds fine.

I tried different options for `--ghc-build` to no avail; switched between clang and gcc; all my stack and other local Haskell packages are up to date (I'm on Arch Linux).

I want to use the latest version of Megaparsec 7.0.4, which is not part of lt-12.4 (version 6.5). I can work around this problem with dependency options in stack/cabal, but I wonder why not even an empty/new project won't build with lts-13.2 on my machine (lts-13.1 won't work either). [This problem](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3518) is very similiar to mine, but none the solutions presented there work for me.

What am I missing?

Comment: I had this problem some time ago. To be honest, I still have it: `stack setup` fails for ghc-8-6-3 (tinfo6 variant) install. Somehow it does not really seem to matter: I can run `stack build` in the same directory just fine afterwards. I suspect it will come to bite me one day, but for now it works. Could you try if you can actually build after the failed setup?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't for me. But I found some informations and will update my question accordingly.

Comment: Wait, what just happened. I cleaned up my ghc-8-6-3 install to test this, and ghc run ok-ishly - there was an error due to missing export lists, so I assumed it would work. Just to be sure I've fixed the missing lists, and it blew up with exactly the same linker errors. So I did do something to make it work before. Oh well. I feel very stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is a re-emergence of an old problem: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/4497

Seems some config tool sets `("C compiler supports -no-pie", "NO")` in `~/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.6.3/lib/ghc-8.6.3/settings` wrongly; changing this manually to `YES` will let me build my project.

So this problem is apparently a bug in one of the generator tools stack uses. Mind this is a "hotfix"; follow the issue on Github with the link I provided to stay up to date.